# Woocommerce no muestra mis productos en la portada

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Recién hice una instalación de de woocommecer y permití que los los productos que vienen de ejemplo se insertacen en el sitio pero una vez finalizada la instalación no me muestra los productos en la portada solamente sale vacia con un texto que dice :
`¡Bienvenido a tu sitio! Esta es tu página de inicio, que es la que la mayoría de visitantes verán cuando vengan a tu sitio por primera vez.`
tengo instalado storefront y no me muestra nada

Comment: haz intentado reinstarlo?

Answer (score 0):

Es la configuración por defecto de tu instalación, es decir, está mostrando la página marcada como Inicio(home), si deseas que la página inicial muestre tu tienda debes hacer lo siguiente en tu backend:

- Ir al menú **Apariencia** / **Personalizar**
- Una vez dentro de la personalización, ubica el submenú "**Ajustes de Portada**"
- Selecciona "**Una página estática**"
- En la opción "**Página de inicio**", seguro debe estar seleccionado "**Homepage**", así que cambialo por "**Tienda**" o "**Shop**", según como tengas configurada tu instalación.

Y listo, con eso ya en el home, tendrás tus categorías o productos.

La mayoría de las configuraciones permitidas para el StoreFront, se encuentra a través del menú de personalización, claro, en el theme gratuito, está muy limitado todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]